# Zabbix でネットワーク機器を監視するために SNMP OID を指定したいが、 mib ファイルの読み方が分からない

Tags: zabbix, snmp

Zabbix から SNMP を用いて YAMAHA RTX のルーターを監視しようとしています。zabbix の画面を操作した結果、監視したい対象メトリックの SNMP OID を指定しなければならないようだ、と思っています。

少し調べた結果、 SNMP OID の定義は [YAMAHA private MIB](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/docs/mib/index.php) にある MIB ファイルにてなされているようです。このファイルたちを読んでみようとしたのですが、読み方が分かりません。

## 質問

Zabbix に Item を登録するという観点で、これら MIB ファイルたちからどのように SNMP OID を読み取れば良いのでしょうか?

Comment: 全文は会員登録が必要なようですが、こちらの記事が参考になりそうです。 - [図解で知るSNMP――MIB情報のすべて - ITmedia エンタープライズ](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/articles/0705/21/news015.html) / RFC の定義はこちら - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1213

Answer (score -1):

MIBを読むより、実際に SNMP でOIDと値を参照したほうが楽だと思います。

```
$ snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <ip-address>
```

OIDと値がずらずらっと出てきますので必要なものを選んでください。